# Google Checkout disabled but causes Network Error loading Membership tab

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor

Payment processor Google Checkout is disabled, but Civi is still trying to load its file which doesn't exit:
PHP Warning:  require_once(CRM/Core/Payment/Google.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Payment/System.php on line 59

Can I safely delete that payment processor without affecting any contributions that used it (there doesn't appear to be any FKs tying them together)?
Wouldn't it be better to not check for disabled (not supported anymore) processors?

Answer (score 2):

You will also need to disable the google checkout payment processor. This error is now handled in 4.7.31.

Comment: Is there a patch?

Comment: Are the changes isolated to the /Civi/Payment/System.php file from 4.7.31?  Replacing the file does allow the Membership tab to load :)